# Bash for loop to execute commands on remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

So I have a list of servers with n length. I need to open a connection and edit a file and close it.

Here's what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

server_list=(a b c d)

for i in "${server[@]}"; do ssh "${server[@]}"; cd /etc; cp file file.bak; perl -pi -i 's/find/replace/g' file; exit; done
```

The only issue I have is that I can't exit the ssh connection and move on to the next in the array. I have used the `-n`, `-t` and `-T` options to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to NOT have a backup on your remote box, perform your global replace locally the just do `scp file "${server[@]}/etc/"`

Comment: The important thing to understand here is that `ssh "${server[@]}"` is *a distinct command* from `cd /etc`, and as your code is currently written, `cd /etc` won't be run until `ssh "${server[@]}"` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code isn't sending any commands to the `ssh` sessions. Use a heredoc to pass your commands into `ssh`:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    server_list=(a b c d)
    for i in "${server_list[@]}"; do
      #
      # As per Charles' suggestion - "bash -s" makes sure the commands
      # would run with Bash rather than the default shell on the remote
      # server.
      #
      # I have left your commands exactly as in your question.
      # They can be written as a single command as per @chepner's recommendation 
      ssh "$i" bash -s << "EOF"
        cd /etc
        cp file file.bak
        perl -pi -i 's/find/replace/g' file
        exit
EOF
    done
```

Comment: Do you really mean to have everything but the EOF (shebang included) four-spaces off the margin? I tried to edit, but think you had something going on concurrently, so we ended up stomping on each other there.

Comment: Yes, I wanted that code to be indented to make it more readable.

Comment: btw, I'm assuming you mean `ssh "$i"`, vs `ssh "${server[@]}"`

Comment: Hmm. Inasmuch as indenting a shebang makes it no longer functional, I'd argue that at least that first line should be flush. However, if it's your authorial intent, I'll leave it be.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That might have been me; I was trying to remove the `-n` option from `ssh` that would have prevented the heredoc from being read.

Comment: The entire remote script could be reduced to `perl -pi.bak 's/find/replace/g' /etc/file`, rending the heredoc unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `ssh "$i" "bash -s"`, so you aren't relying on the user's configured default interpreter. I mean, for all we know they could be using something completely noncompliant like fish.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's the kind of detail I think one can ignore unless the OP brings it up.

Comment: @chepner, *shrug*. Teach robust practices up-front and one doesn't need to deal with exceptions situationally. The more important case here is when we're substituting arguments into our heredoc -- ie. `set -- $args`, with `printf -v args '%q ' "$@"` or such; in that case, we have no guarantee that contents will eval back to the original values unless the same shell is in use.

Comment: Indented code is easier to read. Sorry I couldn't figure out the formatting.

Comment: A backup of the file needs to be created every time so that if there is an issue a role back is super simple. @CharlesDuffy I was using this "${server[@]}" just for simplicity in the array. Every machine is only bash so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: I have seen the heredoc used once or twice before but I'll have to read up on it and why it worked.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you're going to program that defensively, then surely `sh -s` is a better idea. But if you have the password or other necessary credentials to log in with `ssh`, surely you can find out the login shell ahead of time and pass an appropriate remote command without adding a layer of indirection.

Comment: @chepner, `sh -s` if you've got any arguments being injected shell-quoted for POSIX, but there's not a trivial way to do that for arbitrary input. Even in current ksh, `printf '%q'` uses `$''` extensions at times. I've fallen back to using Python's shlex module on occasion, but relying on a Python interpreter is a bit ugly.

Comment: @zinnadean, ...but you can only ssh to one server per `ssh` command. Expanding an array in that context, and thus listing *all* the servers on your ssh command line as opposed to only the single one you're trying to log into in this pass of the loop, makes no sense.

Comment: @zinnadean, ...the reason the heredoc worked is that it was feeding a document -- the script to run *on stdin* to the remote shell, rather than being written as a bunch of commands for the local shell to run after `ssh` finishes and exits.

Comment: @chepner, (err, `shlex.quote()` in Python 3, `pipes.quote()` in Python 2)